# Mercurial refuses to not ignore Gradle wrapper artifacts

Tags: gradle, mercurial, hgignore

My `.hgignore` file looks like this:

```
syntax: glob

# mercurial files
*.orig
*.rej

# build target and dependency directories
*/target/**
*/target-eclipse/**
.gradle/**
.gradle
*.war
*/wrapper/**
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
*/out/**
*/build/**

# IDE files
.idea/**
.settings/**
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
*.classpath
*.project

# LazyBones
.lazybones/**

# DropWizard
config.yml
config.json

# JMeter Results
*/jmeter/results/*
```

Pay attention to my attempt to exclude `gradle/wrapper/*` from this ignore file:

```
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar
!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

When I run `gradle wrapper` on my project it generates typical Gradle wrapper files. However when I `hg add` I don't see those files (`gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle-wrapper.properties`) added to hg tracking, and when I push my project (`hg push`) I don't see them showing up on the remote repo.

**Have I misconfigured `.hgignore` somehow?** is `hg` still actually *ignoring* my Gradle wrapper artifacts?

Comment: I can't find any documentation of the `!` syntax in [`hg help hgignore`](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgignore.5.html).  Are you sure hg actually supports exclusion?  Can you provide documentation of it?

Comment: That may be the root of my problem @Kevin, I am coming over from git-land. But in googling "hg exclude" I don't see any evidence that `.hgignore` even *supports* exclusions...any ideas? Thanks and +1!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For two specific files, you should just add them manually:

```
hg add gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
hg commit
```

This will work even if they are ignored, and changes will be picked up by subsequent commits automatically.